# Can I use BLOB as primary key in SQLite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

is it ok to use BLOB as the primary key in SQLite3? is it ok to have binary data in the primary key? any gotchas I should know about?

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.34.0 2020-12-01 16:14:00
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE tbl(id BLOB NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, foo TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(id,foo) VALUES(1,"hello");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl;
1|hello
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(id,foo) VALUES(1,"hello");
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: tbl.id
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(id,foo) VALUES(X'00' || 1,"hello");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl;
1|hello
|hello
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(id,foo) VALUES(X'00' || 1,"hello");
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: tbl.id
sqlite> INSERT INTO tbl(id,foo) VALUES(X'00' || 11,"hello");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl;
1|hello
|hello
|hello
sqlite>
```

seems to work alright (except sqlite3 cli interface visually cutting off keys at first NULL)

Comment: Seems like an odd idea.

Comment: Using BLOBs as keys is a bad idea in all database producs. Isn't a 64-bit integer or a GUID string enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a BLOB for a PK works.  `TEXT` items, which also can be very long, also work fine as PKs. I do something like this in code that's in widespread production. (Only works for SQLite after 3.8.2.)

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
    name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY COLLATE BINARY,
    expires INT,
    value BLOB
) WITHOUT ROWID;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS expires ON mytable (expires);
```

"COLLATE BINARY" gets away from case-insensitive equality testing. I do that to make things faster because I don't need case insensitivity.

Is using a BLOB for a PK a good idea? Beats me. It depends on your application. It is unconventional, so you'll do your successors and your future self a favor by writing a few comments explaining the situation.

Comment: well it's a simple HTTP cache ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urlcache(request BLOB NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,time_updated INTEGER NOT NULL,response_body BLOB NOT NULL);``` and the `request`  is HTTP method + URL + http body (eg POST fields), and the problem is that HTTP POST bodies can contain binary data (like a JPG file upload)